# Set mail server and save attachments in specific location

Tags: linux, email-server

One client can only send me their data files through email, so I want to get the attachment from the email and place it in the location automatically when the email arrives or at some time during the day.
How can I set up a mail server on Linux and do what I describe above?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ripMIME](http://pldaniels.com/ripmime/) (or other similar tool) as a [`mailbox_command`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mailbox_command) in Postfix.

```
ripMIME -i <mime file> -d <directory> [-p prefix] [-e [header file]] [-vVh] [--version]
       [--no_nameless] [--unique_names [--prefix|--postfix|--infix]][--paranoid] 
       [--mailbox] [--formdata] [--debug][--no-tnef] [--no-quotedprintable] [--no-uudecode]

Options available :
    -i : Input MIME encoded file (use '-' to input from STDIN)
                    If <mime file> is a directory, it will be recursed
    -d : Output directory
```

So I'd try (but haven't actually tested) to use something like this:

```
mailbox_command = /path/to/ripMIME - -d /tmp/attachments --prefix
```

If this doesn't work, another approach could be run the `ripMIME` against mailbox (or Maildir) in a `cron` job that first extracts all the attachments and then removes the mailbox file, e.g.

```
ripMIME -i /home/mailuser/mail/Inbox -d /home/mailuser/attachments --prefix
rm /home/mailuser/mail/Inbox
```

Removing the mailbox after extraction helps to avoid creation of multiple attachment files from the same message, while `--prefix` helps to avoid overwriting existing attachments, if your client uses the same filename on another day.

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches that you can configure on the receiving user.  Two common ones are a `.forward`, and the `procmail` program.

The `.forward` file can execute a program to process the incoming mail.  This is useful if all mail for that user needs to be processed.  You may need to add the program to the list of approved programs that can be run in a `.forward` file.

I use `procmail` which allow me to process specific files, and deliver other messages normally.  It is possible to create a copy and process it, while delivering the message normally.